# Screen Space Ambient Occlusion (SSAO) being rendered for clipped meshes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, urp

I am working on a small game where I only want to draw the objects (mesh) when it is inside an invicible box. I have gotten the clipping to work so that the mesh is only rendered inside the box (using the solution mentioned here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1875660/urp-render-only-whats-inside-a-cube.html

The only annoyance now is that even when the mesh is clipped, the SSAO is still being rendered as you can see in the following image (in the red box):

[image]

I assume it is because the object is still contributing to the depth normals - but I am unable to find more information about this - or even if this is the actual issue.

Do any of you have a suggestion for how to prevent this from happening?

I am using Unity 2021.2.8f and URP v12.1.3 btw

Comment: I'm not an expert but I seem to remember that was one of the benefits of HDRP pipeline?  But yeah....HDRP

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Postprocessing effect SSAO is applied to all layers seen (not culled) by your main camera. Try to put the object on a different layer and ignore it on your main camera.
You could also integrate an additional forward renderer (+ new camera) to your project, which does not use the SSAO effect and takes care of your object.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I see two possible issues with this: 1) I do want SSAO (or rather Ambient Occlusion) on my meshes but only rendered while the mesh is not being excluded outside the invicible box I created around the terrain mesh. 2) Shadows would not be cast on meshes between the two cameras.

I am starting to think that per-object ambient occlusions would probably be a better solution.